# List all the tags in a WordPress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I need to list all the tags with at least 1 published post in a WordPress blog.

The list is about the full blog and not related to the current post.

What code would you use?

Comment: What code did you try? Did you at least google something like 'Wordpress show all tags'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get all tags of published posts Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167379/get-all-tags-of-published-posts-wordpress)

Answer (score 5):

```
<ul class="tag-manually">    
<?php
    $tags = get_tags('post_tag'); //taxonomy=post_tag
    
    if ( $tags ) :
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) : ?>
            <li class="tag-item-manually"><a class="tag" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $tag->name ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $tag->name ); ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$tags = get_tags();
$html = '<ul>';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
if($tag->slug != "migliori"){
$tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
$html .= "<li><a href='{$tag_link}' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
$html .= "{$tag->name}</a></li>";

        }
}
$html .= '</ul>';
echo $html;
```

This works.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and worked for me.

```
<?php
    $tags = get_tags();
    if ($tags) {
?><ul class="tags"><?php
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '" 
              title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tag-
              >name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tag->name.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '<li><a href="#">View All</a><span class="arrow"></span>
</li>'; ?></ul>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
edit this code and work for me !!!
<ul class="tags">


    <?php

    $tags = get_tags('post_tag'); //taxonomy=post_tag
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($tags);
    //var_dump($tags);
    if ( $tags ) :
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) : ?>
            <li><a class="tag" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $tag->name ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $tag->name ); ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to this code? To me, it looks like a scrambled copy of other answers

Comment: But this code show all tags. But i showing particular single post tag listing.
can you use this code.
<?php the_tags(
 '<ul class="tags">
<li class="tag">', '</li><li class="tag">', '</li></ul>'
 );
 ?>